# Axios Dynamic Parameters

Tags: variables, dynamic, axios, get

Declare a variable then pass it into GET request variable options. Everything in my code works independently, but once I try to pass the variable into the options parameter it comes back undefinded.

Am I missing a step?

```
function getEmail() {
 emailInput = document.querySelector('input').value;
}

var options = {
 method: 'GET',
 ...
 params :{
  email: emailInput
 }

axios.request
....
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.